# how to create a dynamic table in a webpage

Tags: html, dataframe, web

I am trying to learn how to create webpage with a "dynamic" table inside. I have zero experience in creating webpages but still I was able to construct the shape of the table by means of the use of html (the image below is a very basic in a very basic version):

[image]

For summarizing, let's say I want that the web page allows you to introduce A, B, ... J manually using the keyboard as input and it should show you automatically the sum of all of the rows in the column K. I have no idea what technology/code should I use... javascript? PHP? I have good skills in python, could it help somehow? I would like to do it as fast as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by manually creating the table and adding [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) that listen to changes in the table [inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). You can then use the values of the table inputs to calculate the output and display it in the K column:

```js
const inputs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
// Get the output column
const output = document.getElementById('output');

// Calculate the total from all inputs
function calculate() {
  // Start with zero
  let total = 0;
  // For each element, get the value and add it to total.
  inputElements.forEach(inputElement => {
    // If the element does not have a value, we just add 0 (this is what the "|| 0" is for)
    total += Number(inputElement.value) || 0;
  });
  // Display the total in the output column
  output.innerHTML = total;
}

// Get all the input columns
const inputElements = inputs.map(input => document.getElementById(`input-${input}`));
// Add Event Listeners to all the input columns
inputElements.forEach(inputElement => inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate));
```

```css
table input {
  width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<table id="container">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>
      <th>K</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="input-A" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-B" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-C" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-D" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-E" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-F" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-G" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-H" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-I" type="number" /></td>
      <td><input id="input-J" type="number" /></td>
      <td id="output"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```